# ¿ Solución para Error Pylint Unable to import 'module'?

Tags: django, validación, vscode

[image: [pylint] Unable to import 'module' [import-error]]

En realidad no afecta en nada funcional, solo que marca errores donde no los hay, y bueno ensucia un poco el proceso de programar... desde ya gracias.

Comment: debes definir el entorno virtual de python en visual studio code

Comment: revisa lo siguiente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270385/vscode-error-when-importing-django-module/52872276#52872276

Answer (score 4):

Conforme la documentación de VS Code para [especificar un interprete](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) en este caso Pylint, esto se puede hacer definiendo el Python Path en los Settings de tu VS Code, en las opciones de la extensión de Python casi al final de su sección y poniendo la ubicación de tu folder de instalación de Python.

File > Preferences > Settings > Workspace > Extensions > Python
[image: File > Preferences > Settings > Workspace > Extensions > Python]

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes de agregar la dirección de donde tienes python al path de vscode
En mi caso que uso linux, la dirección es:

> /usr/bin/python

Pero si usas windows, debes de copiar y pegar la dirección (incluyendo el c://) al path de vscode, al momento que lo hagas; vscode te pedirá que instales pylint, ya que si te pide que instales pylint; quiere decir que la dirección que has puesto, está correcta.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el comando "`Where python`" en `cmd` para encontrar la dirección donde esta instalado python, y con eso modificas la ruta en `settings` del vs code